# Unable to access shared folder in Win 7 homegroup via IP address

Tags: windows-7, windows, dns, ip, homegroup

I have 3 Win-7 64 bit machines in a homegroup. MAC addressing enabled on the router. Machine A, B and C.

All are in a homegroup. I want to share a folder on machine B to the rest of the group so I share with homegroup (read/write allowed). I jump on machine A and C to test, and am able to click network and open machine B and access and modify the shared folder via explorer.
I try the same via windows key run explorer, by typing in \machineb\share and I am able to access and modify the folder. However, when I type the IP address (192.168.0.13) it will no resolve and I get a "Windows cannot access \path\share."

-I run it in safe mode with no results. Here are my troubleshooting efforts:

-removed all machines from homegroup and and created a new one for all to join 
-tested this process on machine C. Machine A and B are able to access the share on C via hostname and IP address. 
-ran ipconfig /flush dns on all machines. Then ran net stop "dns client" and net start "dns client" 
-restarted router -ran problematic machine (B) in safe mode (no anti-virus). 
-ran the other machines in safe mode. 
-on machine A, ran net use to map P: as the machine B share (machineb\share) by mapping to its host name. Successful drive mapping and ability to access. When I try the same to the IP address it's fails again.
-disabled firewall on both ends

Why can't I access this folder via IP address? I'm pretty sure I'm putting in the right address as shown by ipconfig.

Any ideas? Would MAC address filtering have anything to do with it? I may try to remove/add the problematic machine at router level. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Homegroup operates over IPv6.  This is why you can't access them by IP address (unless you were to type in their IPv6 address).

Comment: I'm able to access other shared folders on other machines via IPv4. I just can't connect to machine B this way.

Comment: Are those computers using HomeGroup as well?  I'm betting that if you turned HomeGroup off and shared out a folder the classic way you'd be able to access it again.  It'a ll in the protocol used to access the share.  If somehow it occurs over SMB, then that's IPv4 and it works.  But if the only access is through HomeGroup, then that's IPv6

Comment: They're all in a homegroup. I don't understand what you mean by IPv6. I can access the other homegroup machines via ipv4. Why not machine B?

Answer (score 0):

Start from disabling the firewall on target PC, where shared folder is located. Had the same issue: my PC can open shared folder from one PC and cannot from another. I checked Windows Firewall on 'another' and opened inbound TCP:445 port for wider range of source IP addresses so it include 'my PC' and everything works fine now.